# How to have a .sh file run @ a certain time

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi

I have a .sh file on my desktop - pifm_morning.sh - that I want to rn every day at 7:15 am, and then run pifm.sh (also on the desktop) untrill 7:15 am the next morning, when pifm_morning.sh will run. How can I set this up?

If it helps, I am on a raspberry pi.
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to the site. Have you looked into `cron`?

Comment: More reqs needed; do you want to run `pifm` only after `pifm_morning` completes? Will it only run if `pifm_morning` exits with non-zero (no error). Do you want `pifm` to run from that point, all the way to the next morning, when `pifm_morning` kicks off? In which case, do you need to ensure that `pifm` exits prior to running the morning process? If yes to any of these, than you need to think of this from a transactional perspective.

Comment: @AdminBee I saw stuff about it online, but it said that it starts before the GUI, and you lose the GUI of the OS. On a raspberry pi, at least.

Comment: @christianlc pifm_morning.sh will just play a 5 minute audio file at 7:15 am, and then I want it to run pifm.sh, which will run untill 7:15 am the next morning. Basically, for the next 23 hours and 55 minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### This will clear your old crontab.

Setup a crontab like so, if your user **is not** the default user pi change it:

```
15 7 * * * /home/pi/Desktop/pifm_morning.sh; /home/pi/Desktop/pifm.sh
```

Add it with:

```
crontab - <<<'15 7 * * * /home/pi/Desktop/pifm_morning.sh; /home/pi/Desktop/pifm.sh'
```

#### And this will clear your old crontab

Remove it with

```
crontab -ri
```

Comment: Note that the last command (`crontab -ri`) also removes _other_ jobs that may exist in the crontab.

Comment: Yea, but the first command literaly also removes other jobs

Comment: @Julian I read online that crontab, at least on a rasberry pi, overrides the GUI, so I have no access to the GUI. Is that true?

Comment: @horace I dont think, but check the current crontab before running commands `crontab -l`

Comment: @Julian You are right, thanks!